# Checking if $X(t) = \exp(t/2)\cos(W(t))$, with $W(t)$ a Wiener process, is a martingale

Tags: stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, martingales

This is what I've done:

Let $s < t$ and $F_t$ be a filtration adapted to $W(t)$
$$E[e^{t/2}\cos(W(t))|F_s] = e^{t/2} E[\cos(W(t)) - \cos(W(s)) + \cos(W(s))|F_s]$$
$$= e^{t/2} [E[\cos(W(t)) - \cos(W(s))|F_s] + \cos(W(s))]$$
Because of the independence of the increments:
$$= e^{t/2} [E[\cos(W(t)) - \cos(W(s))] + \cos(W(s))]$$
This is where I'm stuck. I don't know how to calculate $E[\cos(W(t)) - \cos(W(s))]$.

Following [the suggestion from Did in the comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1596521/154124) in this question, I can do this:
$$E[\cos(W(t)) - \cos(W(s))] = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi (t-s)}}\int_{\mathbb{R}}(\cos(x) - \cos(y)).e^{-(x-y)^2/2(t-s)}dx$$

But I don't know if it is correct.

Edit: OMG! I made an horrible mistake. The increments $W(t) - W(s)$ are independent, not $\cos(W(t)) - \cos(W(s))$. With the hints from [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/143190) and the one from Siron everything got clearer now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find $\mathbb{E}[\cos(W(t))]$ you could try integrating the density function. However, that might turn out to be messy. Instead, recall that
$$\cos x = \frac{e^{ix}+e^{-ix}}{2},$$
and hence
\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}[\cos(W(t))] = \mathbb{E}\left[\frac{e^{iW(t)}+e^{-iW(t)}}{2}\right],
\end{align}
where $\mathbb{E}[e^{iW(t)}]$ is the characteristic function of $W(t)$ evaluated in $1$.

Answer (score 2):

The function $u(t,x)=e^{t/2}\,\cos(x)$ satisfies the heat equation ${d\over dt}u+{1\over 2}\Delta_x u=0,$ so that, by Ito's formula, 
$u(t,W_t)=e^{t/2}\,\cos(W_t)$ is a martingale.